# Creating a Website From Scratch With MVC, Which ORM is Better, EF or NHibernate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

I want to create a website, with many users and obviously with a big amount of database, and I do not have experience in either EF or NHibernate, what is recommended one for me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [nhibernate, entity framework, active records or linq2sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql)

Answer (score 4):

EF is very well integrated with .NET and Visual Studio. Gives you a very good designer inside Visual Studio, and leverage LINQ to write queries that are very easy to read.

For me, this is a no-brainer. I would go with EF4 without a doubt.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing first time I would recommend you to go with EF because its easy to paly with it no more configuration and hidden properties....no need to apply any extra efforts just add the object and your task is done.

but if you are looking better performance go for NHibernate.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on which database you're using on the backend.  If you're using any of the Microsoft databases then EF is the way to go.

Oracle doesn't have a client that supports EF yet (it is coming), so you'll need to use NHibernate to talk to Oracle until they update their client.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for NHibernate, because it allows you to tweak performance better than EF and is better portable across different databases.

When using asp.net mvc for the first time, you can consider using [S#arp architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/). It uses NHibernate. On the website it is explained clearly how to get started quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Neither.

I've used EF for the past year and the problems i've had are not worth the hassle.

I've told my peers this - if i could go back in time i would use stored procedures with a thin API abstracting it away.

Either that or use a "lightweight" ORM like Dapper or Massive.

EF gave me too much bloat, complexity with associations (particularly inheritance model), bug's never fixed, and problems with "updating" entities in a stateless environment such as MVC.

Don't really care if i get downvoted - just want to put in my two cents. Initially i loved EF, because i came from a L2SQL background so it was an easy transition. But once i started digging under the covers i found out how painful it is to work with.

That being said - i haven't used NHibernate so i can't comment on that, only commenting on Entity Framework.

Stick close to the metal - you'll get better performance in the long run. Write code in the "real" model - SQL, use indexes, let SQL Server (or Oracle)'s engine do what it does best.

As consistent and intelligent the LINQ framework is, IMO (and that's all we can do here, give opinions), LINQ-Entities just does not generate good enough SQL when you have a non-basic model (which most people do).

**My EF4 Pet Peeves:**

1. **Can't eager load only certain "types"**. E.g if you have `Post` and `Location` as a `*..*`, and you have `Question` as a type of Post, there is no way to retrieve a `Location` and just it's `Question`'s. You must either eager load *all* `Posts`, or use an anonymous type projection. In general, eager loading is extremely painful.
2. **Updating relationships on an existing entity, in a stateless, POCO scenario.** Again, if you have a `Post`, which has many `Location`'s, and you want to *change* the `Location` an existing `Post` is linked to, there is no easy way to do so with an MVC controller action. In order for EF to deem a relationship `modified` when you work with POCO's, you need to actually set it to modified. But if you have POCO's, the relationships are usually `ICollection<TPOCO>`, so you don't have these built in methods. You end up manually setting the Entity State in the guts of the OSM when you do `Save`. I ended up manually merging entities in, basically left-to-right.
3. **No batching of statements.** I believe NHibernate supports this. This is big problem with EF, especially if you want to update multiple objects in a single trip. I usually end up using a stored procedure, defeating the point of EF in the first place.
4. **Can't map lookup tables to enum's.**. Okay, so this isn't a huge issue, but it's an annoying one. Lookup tables are a natural fit for an enum, but EF simply doesn't support it - despite pleas from the community from day 1. No idea why this hasn't been put in.